# Snap to Lines option in Inkscape tracing

Tags: svg, raster, trace, inkscape

Does anyone know if there is a "snap to lines" option while tracing bitmap in Inkscape. Adobe Illustrator live trace has this option to help "straighten" slightly curved lines or lines which are slightly off from 0 or 90 degrees. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this option is not available so far.
The best you can do at the moment is to play around with the options

**Suppress speckles**

**Smooth corners**

**Optmize paths**

on the Options tab of the Trace Bitmap popup window.

Comment: Thanks mrcl. I will try these options